# Update documents nested multiple levels in an array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have this JSON structure in MongoDb and want to update changing a specific value of a particular item in a nested array. I would like to change the key **targetAreaId** from **USER_MESSAGE** to **VISUAL_MESSAGE**.

```
{
"_id" : "5cde9f482f2d5b924f492da2",
"scenario" : "SCENARIOX",
"mediaType" : "VISUAL",
"opCon" : "NORMAL",
"stepConfigs" : [ 
    {
        "stepType" : "STEPX",
        "enabled" : true,
        "configs" : [ 
            {
                "contentTemplateId" : "5cde9f472f2d5b924f492973",
                "scope" : "STANDARD",
                "key" : "CONTENT"
            }, 
            {
                "priorityId" : "5cde9f472f2d5b924f49224f",
                "scope" : "STANDARD",
                "key" : "PRIORITY"
            }, 
            {
                "targetAreaId" : "USER_MESSAGE",
                "scope" : "STANDARD",
                "key" : "TARGET_AREA"
            }
        ],
        "description" : "XPTO"
    }
],
"scope" : "STANDARD" }
```

How can I do it in the same time?

**EDIT**

I am trying this way:

```
var cursor = db.getCollection('CollectionX').find({
  "scenario": "SCENARIOX",
  "stepConfigs.stepType": "STEPX",
  "stepConfigs.configs.key": "TARGET_AREA"
});

if (cursor.hasNext()) {
    var doc = cursor.next();
    doc.stepConfigs.find(function(v,i) { 
        if (v.stepType == "STEPX") {
           doc.stepConfigs[i].configs.find(function(w,j) {
                if (w.key == "TARGET_AREA") {
                    var result = db.getCollection('CollectionX').update(
                        { "_id" : doc._id },
                        { "$set" : { doc.stepConfigs[i].configs[j].targetAreaId: "VISUAL_MESSAGE" }}
                    );
                }
           });
        };
    });
} else {
    print("Step does not exist");
}
```

But the error below is occurring:

***Error: Line 15: Unexpected token .***

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's possible.

You can update the specific element you want using this query:

```
db.test_array.updateOne({}, {
    $set: {
        "stepConfigs.$[firstArray].configs.$[secondArray].targetAreaId": "VISUAL_MESSAGE"
    }
}, {
    arrayFilters: [{
        "firstArray.stepType": "STEPX"
    }, {
        "secondArray.targetAreaId": "USER_MESSAGE"
    }]
})
```

But pushing in the same array at the same time does render this (this was for the original model, but it's still the same problem, you can't $set and $push in the same array this way):

```
> db.test_array.updateOne({"step.type":"B"},{$push:{"step.$.configs":{"className":"something"}}, $set:{"step.$.configs.$[secondArray].targetAreaId":"TA-1"}},{arrayFilters:[{"secondArray.targetAreaId":"TA-2"}]})
2019-09-06T13:53:44.783+0200 E QUERY    [js] WriteError: Updating the path 'step.$.configs.$[secondArray].targetAreaId' would create a conflict at 'step.$.configs' :
```

Comment: Occurs this error: "errmsg" : "cannot use the part (step of step.$[firstArray].configs.$[secondArray].targetAreaId) to traverse the element

Comment: Can you maybe give me the full document on which this happens? The document I based myself on was this one:```{
 "_id" : "1",
 "className" : "com.BLABLA",
 "scenario" : "A",
 "step" : [
  {
   "type" : "B",
   "enabled" : true,
   "configs" : [
    {
     "className" : "com.XPTO",
     "targetAreaId" : "TA-1",
     "scope" : "S",
     "key" : "TA"
    },
    {
     "className" : "something"
    }
   ],
   "description" : "XXXX"
  }
 ]
}```

Comment: Updated the answer. It still works to update a specific element. But not to push.